# Swagger request with 'xml' as string shows strange behavior

Tags: json, xml, swagger

I made an API-call so you can pass a XML-configuration as body parameter (string).
When called with the following xml: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body></body>`
It returns that my request has a strange ending.

I tried:

- Remove the quotes in the XML and replace them by `&quot;` -> did not work
- Put Everything on a single line -> Seems to help a bit, but not sure...

Someone has experience with passing XML strings in a JSON-file?
I'm out of ideas... I'm pretty sure my functionality works, I just need to test it with swagger...

*Extra Info*

-Post request- 
[Link Swagger post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu7rq.jpg)

-Error-
Unexpected end of file. Rule 1, position 15

Comment: How do you send the request? What error you get?

Comment: @Helen I added more details in my post.

Comment: Note the "Parameter content type" (below the input field) is `application/json` instead of `application/xml` - this means something's wrong with your Swagger spec. Did you write it manually or generated from source code? If you wrote the spec manually, please post the spec. If you generated it from code - post your source code.

Comment: @Helen I want it to be application/json, I want to pass the xml in a json-string which I convert in my WebAPI(2) to a C# string which I then convert to an xml-object. (All my current endpoints are json.)

Comment: I want to add more parameters to the body request which I want to be in JSON which is the reason I want it to stay JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If your API expects a *string* (not a JSON object), you should send your XML enclosed in quotes, with inner quotes escaped as `\"`, etc. - that is, encoded as a proper JSON string:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><body></body>"
```

Or if your API expects an *object* whose property contains an XML string, you should use something like:

```json
{
  "someWrapperProperty": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><body></body>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tonight.